# git commit throws error '[<-'

Tags: r, windows, git, rstudio, githooks

Does anybody have an idea, how I can fix this? `git commit -a -m "message here` works fine for other projects and previous commits this day were all ok.
Now, it throws the error:

> Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, 1, "Date", value = "2016-07-29") :
>   Indizierung außerhalb der Grenzen
>   Ausführung angehalten

The error message is something like:

> index out of bounds

Please let me know if you need any further information.

Here is a screenshot: [image]

**Edit**: @Carsten guessed right! I have a hook running. But I cannot see why it should stop working from one to another minute... (It still does not work)

```
#!C:/R/R-3.2.2/bin/x64/Rscript

# License: CC0 (just be nice and point others to where you got this)
# Author: Robert M Flight <rflight79@gmail.com>, github.com/rmflight
inc <- TRUE # default
# get the environment variable and modify if necessary
tmpEnv <- as.logical(Sys.getenv("inc"))
if (!is.na(tmpEnv)) {
  inc <- tmpEnv
}

# check that there are files that will be committed, don't want to increment version if there won't be a commit
fileDiff <- system("git diff HEAD --name-only", intern = TRUE)

if ((length(fileDiff) > 0) && inc) {

  currDir <- getwd() # this should be the top level directory of the git repo
  currDCF <- read.dcf("DESCRIPTION")
  currVersion <- currDCF[1,"Version"]
  splitVersion <- strsplit(currVersion, ".", fixed = TRUE)[[1]]
  nVer <- length(splitVersion)
  currEndVersion <- as.integer(splitVersion[nVer])
  newEndVersion <- as.character(currEndVersion + 1)
  splitVersion[nVer] <- newEndVersion
  newVersion <- paste(splitVersion, collapse = ".")
  currDCF[1,"Version"] <- newVersion
  currDCF[1, "Date"] <- strftime(as.POSIXlt(Sys.Date()), "%Y-%m-%d")
  write.dcf(currDCF, "DESCRIPTION")
  system("git add DESCRIPTION")
  cat("Incremented package version and added to commit!\n")
}
```

Comment: Missing " at the end helps?

Comment: No. I tried from RStudio and from terminal... I also tried a `git init`, restart RStudio, restart the laptop. I even `reverted` to the previous commit, pulled, made a tiny change - but even then a simple commit `git commit -a -m "Test"`throwed the error.

Comment: The output looks more like a "R" error than a git error.
Maybe a git hook fails? Look into the folder `.git/hooks/`, you might find a file `prepare-commit-msg` or `pre-commit` executing some R scripts.
For more infomation see https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks

Comment: @Carsten: Thank you for your hint. I was surprised about the R-code, but now it makes sence. Do you have an idea how I can solve the problem? I posted the hook but have no clue how to do trouble shouting in a hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Carsten: Using `print` statements I could track the error in the hook file. In the end it was a stupid bug, where `Date` was accidentially deleted (=missing) in the `description` file.